# Exchange version from VSTO Add-In

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, mapi

Is there a simple way to retrieve the Exchange version from a VSTO Add-In. I noticed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197440/determining-version-of-exchange-server-on-the-system-using-c-sharp) that WMI might be an option. I would like to avoid powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange server version is stored in the `0x663B0102` property in the store's profile section. In older versions of Outlook (2003 and below) in `0x661B0003`. It is only accessible through Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) - read `PR_EMSMDB_SECTION_UID` from `IMsgStore`, use it to call [IMAPISession::OpenProfileSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/imapisession-openprofilesection), read `0x663B0102` from `IProfSect`.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language - I am its author) is an option, it exposes [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`ExchangeMailboxServerVersion` and [RDOExchangeMailboxStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOExchangeMailboxStore).`ServerVersion` properties.